# String To DateTime Exception

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have this `String` :

```
05/09/2013 23:23
```

And i want to convert it to `DateTime` with this:

```
DateTime alarmDateTime = new DateTime();
alarmDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm", null);
```

And i get this Exception:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Any idea why it happens?

Comment: what is: `YYYYY`? do yo mean `yyyy`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the year should be lower case 'y'.  There is also no need to instantiate the date time on the first line as the value is overwritten on the second.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime alarmDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

If date seperator in your system is `"/"` then just changing YYYY to yyyy will work.

If it is not then use this

```
 string date = "05/09/2013 23:23";

 DateTime alarmDateTime = new DateTime();
 alarmDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", 
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[image]